# SQL query Multiple Sums and Groups

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, distinct, ansi-sql

i have the Following Table that has multiple dishes in multiple quantities for different dates

```
[Dishes]
    Date                  |   Dish_Id    |  Quantity  |   Price   |   Total
============================================================================
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000          5             1           50.00       50.00
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000          3             1           30.00       30.00
2016-09-10 00:00:00.000          10            1          100.00      100.00
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000          5             1           50.00       50.00
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000          7             1           70.00       70.00
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000          7             1           70.00       70.00
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000          3             1           30.00       30.00
2016-09-10 00:00:00.000          3             1           30.00       30.00
```

What i want to do is a SQL query that will combine every unique/distinct Dish_Id and sum its equivalent Quantities And Total but in groups acording to the Date value without affecting its price per item
Thus if you ran the query on the table above it would produce the following result sets:

```
[Result]
    Date                  |   Dish_Id    |  Quantity  |   Price   |   Total
============================================================================
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000          5             2           50.00      100.00
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000          3             2           30.00       60.00
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000          7             2           70.00      140.00                
2016-09-10 00:00:00.000          10            1          100.00      100.00
2016-09-10 00:00:00.000          3             1           30.00       30.00
```

im sure a GroupBy is the correct Approach but im not sure how to sum() multiple columns and just using the groupby for the "Date" Value without affecting the "Price"
Something like this maybe

```
select Date, Dish_Id, sum(quantity), Price, Sum(Total)
from Dishes
group by Date, Price
```

EDIT************
GOT IT WORKING NOW 
THANKS EVERYONE

Comment: Looks like your query would **almost** work.  You need to add dish_ID to your group by. and remove the ?? from price.  If that doesn't do it what's wrong?

Comment: nop its not working, it just displays full results without grouping or sum

Comment: You should post your working code to help others.  I"d be interested to know if you just eliminated the price column or if you grouped by it and Dish_ID..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT DATE
    ,dish_id
    ,sum(quantity) AS Quantity_Total
    ,sum(price * quantity) AS TotalPrice
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATE
    ,dish_id
```

[image]

See here for online example/sandbox http://rextester.com/OLAJ52246

Comment: i have tryed this output but with the same results, the results are not grouping the same Dish_id, not grouping anything at all also not making the "SUM"

Comment: I am not sure what you're saying - I just added a screenshot and the results of my query are the same as your desired results table, except I omitted the price column for simplicity. What is the desired output?

Comment: If you need the price column, then use this query `SELECT DATE
 ,dish_id
 ,sum(quantity) AS Quantity_Total
    ,price
 ,sum(price * quantity) AS TotalPrice
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATE
 ,dish_id
,price`  http://rextester.com/JKCNI91097

Comment: yeah, srry just make it workign not i was missing a come and the Dish_id in my query thanks this anwser is correct =)